# Maximum length of a trail in a hypercube

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A trail is an alternating sequence of vertices and edges but edges cannot be repeated.

Given a hypercube $Q_{n}$ what will be the maximum length of the trail?

My attempt:

For base case $Q_{2}$ we will have a maximum trail length of $4$.

I came up with this recurrence relation based on the intuition that $Q_{3}$ is formed from connection $2$ $Q_{2}$ hypercubes, this relation happens to be working fine up to $Q_{4}$(beyond which is really hard to draw)

$ T(n) = 2*T(n-1) + 1 $

$T(2) = 4$

Solving it we get $T(n) = 2^{n} + 2^{n-2} - 1$

1. Is this recurrence relation correct, if yes please provide a reason.
2. If it's wrong any other alternate approach or idea that you have please share.

Comment: Research math:  http://cobweb.cs.uga.edu/~potter/CompIntell/IEAAIE-snakes.pdf

Comment: @DavidG.Stork That document is interesting and somewhat related but not addressing the question posed here. The PDF talks about "induced" paths and here we just want any non-self-overlapping path.

Comment: @kabenyuk let's take $Q_{3}$ as an example length of maximum trail will be $9$ but total number of edges will be $12$.

Comment: If $n$ is even, then for $Q_{n}$ the maximal trail length is $2^{n-1}n$. If $n$ is odd, then apparently the maximal trail length is $2^{n-1}(n-1)+2$. Today seems to be a bad day for me ):

Comment: You seem to be right $T(Q_3)=9$ and in general, if $n$ is odd, then apparently the maximum trail length is $2^{n-1}(n-1)+1$.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A072934, though the last entry of $T(8)=255$ seems unusual. Before that $T(n) = 2\cdot T(n-1)+1$ for odd $n$; $T(n) = 2\cdot T(n-1)+2$ for even $n$. I have no proof, but that does seem like a plausible recurrence.

Comment: @nickgard It's not clear to me what that sequence is counting exactly. As pointed out in the answer, $Q_4$ has an Eulerian tour with $32$ edges; in the sequence, $a(4)=20$, so *something* has to be constraining us further. (But we *are* reusing vertices, or else we wouldn't be able to get even that high.) Maybe the "found using a greedy algorithm" comment means that the values found in the OEIS are not actually optimal?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Having now seen the posted answer, I agree with you. In the OEIS sequence maybe _non-crossing_ has some special meaning at vertices (for example, in a planar graph imagine not being able to go straight ahead at a "crossroads"). I'm also not sure what _greedy algorithm_ means in the context of a non-weighted graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then the longest trail is an eulerian cycle. As it goes through every edges, it has length $2^{n-1}n $.

If $n$ is odd, we can find an eulerian cycle that goes through every edges except a perfect matching. This cycle is of length $2^{n-1}n-2^{n-1} $. We can extend this trail with one more edge, giving a trail of length $2^{n-1}(n-1)+1 $. This is easy to see it is optimal, as the trail has an even amount of edges adjacent to each vertices that are not the extremities.